# Workflow automatization question (macro recorder/command playback)

Tags: interface, workflow

I have a cube. I select a face of it, and do the following 3 steps:

1. Insert face
2. Extrude face
3. Resize face

Is there a way to save these 3 actions to be able to use on any other faces? Like a hotkey/macro to improve the workflow. What keywords to search for this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: maybe with a script but, without script, you could do several faces at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the free command recorder addon for this very thing and it works well.  It has apparently been changed to action recorder and is developed by the same author.  I haven't tried this new version yet though.  You can find details here.

[Action recorder](https://www.blendernation.com/2020/08/22/versionup-action-recorder-free-add-on/)

Comment: This add-on should be shipped as standard, IMO. It's an obvious need.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you can reduce this sequence to a single operation, to make it available to <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>, repeat last operation. Even taking into account that the  <kbd>I</kbd> inset operation has a 'Depth' setting, which can easily go unnoticed.

But as @moonboots has commented, you can execute the operation on multiple faces simultaneously:

- Set Pivot to 'Individual Origins', and Orientation to 'Normal'
- Set the Inset tool to 'Individual'
- <kbd>I</kbd> inset
- <kbd>E</kbd> extrude
- <kbd>S</kbd> scale faces

[image]

The XY guidelines in the last move in the gif are there because I instinctively used  <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> to scale, which is actually unnecessary.

Comment: .. but @Mark Grant's answer is probably more like what you're after :)